# create row in a table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to add a table row.But It doesn't added.I checked in ddms.

```
@Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        long rowID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
        if (rowID > 0) {
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
    }


static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
            + id +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + name + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + trackNumber +"VARCHAR not null )";
```

I have added the trackNumber in database table.It is not added.I checked in ddms.Anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Where is the insert query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the spaces...

This:

```
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
        + id +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + name + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + trackNumber +"VARCHAR not null )";
```

Should be

```
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
        + id +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + name + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + trackNumber +" VARCHAR not null )";
```

**[EDIT]**

Since your table has been created (with erroneous field names and types), you need to recreate the table.

To do so, increase the value of the constant **DATABASE_VERSION** to 2 and rerun the code.
This way, the onUpgrade() method will fire, so deleting and recreating your table.

Comment: Now increase the value of the constant DATABASE_VERSION to 2 and retry. This way, the `onUpgrade()` method will fire, so deleting and recreating your table.

Comment: yes it added successfully.Thank you very much.can you please explain why?

Comment: The `onUpgrade()` method fires only if the DATABASE_VERSION value is greater than the one previously used.

Comment: I have to add the 8 values then I can change the database version every changes 3,4 or 5 so on?

Comment: **NO**!! Only when you alter the database structure. Not when you modify the table contents. Otherwise the table/s would be destroyed and recreated every time. And the contents would be lost.